# Accessing xml from jsp on tomcat server is throwing FileNotFoundException trying to access .keystore?

Tags: xml, jsp, tomcat, keystore, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to access an XML file from JSP on my Tomcat server.  The error is from Catalina's protocol handler and the exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException trying to access my .keystore in the 'documents and settings' folder for my signed-on user (with admin, but not the user that installed the server).

I can provide the stacktrace if that would help ... but my question is more fundamental about secure access to files and where is the keystore configured / used on a Window's install?

Comment: I found this remark in the Apache/Tomcat website regarding tomcat and SSL, which leads me to think that I should not have to configure keystore access to its files (is this assumption true? not true?). "It is important to note that configuring Tomcat to take advantage of secure sockets is usually only necessary when running it as a stand-alone web server."  My server is behind an Apache server.

Comment: Is this related? "When Tomcat starts up, I get an exception like "java.io.FileNotFoundException: {some-directory}/{some-file} not found".
A likely explanation is that Tomcat cannot find the keystore file where it is looking. By default, Tomcat expects the keystore file to be named .keystore in the user home directory under which Tomcat is running (which may or may not be the same as yours :-). If the keystore file is anywhere else, you will need to add a keystoreFile attribute to the <Factory> element in the Tomcat configuration file."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my goodness ... it wasn't the .keystore (I tried fixing that which just changed the error).  It was the JkMount statements in my httpd.conf file.  I did not pass *.xml.

I think I killed two issues with one solution.